# Do NGRX and NGXS create a separate Store instances when created in a TestBed module?

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine, ngrx, ngxs

I want to make sure that using a real Store instance, instead of a mock Store, will  not interfere with my existing store data in my Angular app.  This may be more of a general question about Angular testing modules but I want to direct it specifically towards state management libraries in this case.

Example test module:

```
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        NgxsModule.forRoot([ZooState])
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
    store = TestBed.get(Store);
  }));
```

Example `app.module`

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    NgxsModule.forRoot([ZooState])
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Will the TestBed instance interfere with (actually use) the AppModule instance?  If so, why would they recommend NOT mocking the store in both sets of documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry it's the good way to instantiate the store in your test :)